# Multiple SELECT statements in one query of a function | PHP --- SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need 2 selects to be executed in a function at the same time in a query, because if I put it apart one is executed but the other is not.

This my function:

```
function selectOne($table, $conditions)
{
   
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";
        $i = 0;
                foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
                    
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
               $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    
        $sql = $sql . " LIMIT 1";
    
 
            if($table == "posts"){
    $sql = "SELECT t1.*, t2.name as tipo FROM posts AS t1 LEFT JOIN tipo as t2 ON (t1.tipo_id = t2.id) WHERE t1.id = ?";
            
     $sql = "SELECT t1.*, t2.status as status FROM posts AS t1 LEFT JOIN estado as t2 ON (t1.estado_id = t2.id) WHERE t1.id = ?";
            }  
                
    

        
        $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $conditions);
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        return $records;
    
    }
```

To explain myself better I need to execute these 2 selects in this function, but only one works.

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.*, t2.name as tipo FROM posts AS t1 LEFT JOIN tipo as t2 ON (t1.tipo_id = t2.id) WHERE t1.id = ?";
        
 $sql = "SELECT t1.*, t2.status as status FROM posts AS t1 LEFT JOIN estado as t2 ON (t1.estado_id = t2.id) WHERE t1.id = ?";
```

[IMAGE OF THE PRODUCT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIKkd.png)

as you can see the first query `$sql = "SELECT t1.*, t2.name as tipo FROM posts AS t1 LEFT JOIN tipo as t2 ON (t1.tipo_id = t2.id) WHERE t1.id = ?";`" is not working (This shows me what type it is: "Normal, PLUS").

but the second `$sql = SELECT t1.*, t2.status as status FROM posts AS t1 LEFT JOIN estado as t2 ON (t1.estado_id = t2.id) WHERE t1.id = ?";`" if it is working. This shows me what status it is: "Available, Out stock"

---

Now for example I remove the second query, this: `$sql = "SELECT t1.*, t2.status as status FROM posts AS t1 LEFT JOIN estado as t2 ON (t1.estado_id = t2.id) WHERE t1.id = ?";` it's work. But of course I can't get the other to show up.

[IMAGE OF PRODUCT - TWO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLTkL.png)

---

**NEW QUESTION EDIT**

DATABASE - TABLES AND ROWS:

ESTADO.SQL
[STATUS IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOEze.png)

TIPO.SQL
[TIPO IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0prto.png)

POSTS.SQL
[POST IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVCem.png)

The posts table contains 2 columns which indicate the IDs of the contents, in this case "Ice Cream" has been selected in estado_id (1) and tipo_id (1)

I need my query to link the 3 tables "estado.sql", "tipo.sql", "post.sql" via JOINS and to be able to display the data from the other tables in the product.

Example:

Ice Cream | estado_id (1 = AVAILABLE) | tipo_id (1 = PLUS)

Comment: You can join multiple tables in same query assuming from the queries you posted

Comment: @kelvin | And how can i do that? I have tried in several ways but they all give me an error

Comment: I would start over, with an explanation of the actual problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @Strawberry | I need to execute these 2 SELECTS in the same function, but it turns out that only one is executed and the other rejects it. Currently the second SELECT is working (status) but the first one is not (tipo), and when removing it it works normally.

Comment: @DonOmar . . . Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish is much clearer than "I want to combine these two queries".

Comment: You are overwriting your `$sql` variable, so it's behaving exactly as expected. You can't define two queries to run at the same time, you would need to run them separately. But, as the others already stated, give us a wider picture so we can give you better advice.

Comment: @El_Vanja | This function works for the tabs of the products of my website, for example "drinks, ice cream" then these 2 queries relate 2 different tables of my database using **JOIN** with the main one which is "posts" to indicate if the product is available, finished, and categories. That's why I need to somehow execute these 2 SELECTS with JOINS.

Comment: Please edit your question, present your db structure with some sample data and explain what your desired result would be for the query.

Comment: @El_Vanja Done, I edit the question.

Comment: I'll give this one more shot. You are not providing what we are asking you to provide. You keep explaining the same thing over and over, while we need _new_ information from you. The reason why only the last query works is because you are *overwriting* your `$sql` variable. Please, give us the _structure_ of your db tables (what columns they contain), a sample of data (one or two rows should suffice) and your desired _result_ (meaning exactly what data you want your query to return, not "I want to run two queries").

Comment: @El_Vanja | I'm sorry, what happens is that I'm a little nervous. Done and I edit the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to note that the reason only the last query was being executed is the fact you were overwriting your `$sql` variable. You'd have to do two fetches anyway, so with that out of the way, we can now focus into making it a single query (you can have multiple joins):

```sql
SELECT p.name, t.name, e.status
FROM posts p
    LEFT JOIN tipo t ON t.id = p.tipo_id
    LEFT JOIN estado e ON e.id = p.estado_id
WHERE p.id = ?
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a821a/2) for a test.

This way one query returns everything you need, instead of having to run two of them. If you need more data, just modify your `SELECT` clause per your requirements (for example, if you need more details about the post, I limited myself to the name only).

Bonus advice: when you give your tables an alias, avoid things like `t1`, `t2`, etc. It's ok in a short query, but when you eventually get to bigger queries that join 5-6 or more tables, it's easy to lose track which table was `t2` and which one was `t5`. Try to give them a shorthand that represents their name - in my example I used the initial, since all the tables start with a different letter. Generally, if the table name is short, you can omit the alias assignment altogether and just use the table names:

```sql
SELECT posts.name, tipo.name, estado.status
FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN tipo ON tipo.id = posts.tipo_id
    LEFT JOIN estado ON estado.id = posts.estado_id
WHERE posts.id = ?
```

This works just the same.

The general rule is to make your code readable and explicit (the less deciphering you have to do - for example which table is `t3` - the better). Even if you think "oh, I won't have to join that many tables in this project", maybe you will in the future. And good habits are made early.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly for me, and thank you for clearing up several questions!